# How can I get a JSON object without a name inside a JSON Array from API

Tags: android, arrays, json, api, android-volley

[the JSON data from the API I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY1QY.png)

Part of the code: I've indicated in the code, but I'm not sure what to put:
JSONObject volumeObj = itemsObj.getJSONObject(""); inside the " " based on that API. What can I modify in the code or put in the " " to let me get the objects from the {0}, {1} etc etc?

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);


    // below line is use to make json object request inside that we
    // are passing url, get method and getting json object. .
    JsonObjectRequest booksObjrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // inside on response method we are extracting all our json data.
            try {
                JSONArray itemsArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject itemsObj = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    **JSONObject volumeObj = itemsObj.getJSONObject("");**
                    String title = volumeObj.optString("title");
                    String subtitle = volumeObj.optString("subtitle");
                    JSONArray authorsArray = volumeObj.getJSONArray("authors");
                    String publisher = volumeObj.optString("publisher");
                    String publishedDate = volumeObj.optString("publishedDate");
                    String description = volumeObj.optString("description");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want to obtain the items of the array? The "result" array contains these objects, so you can just access them with indices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
    /* This is the ith object in the array */
    JSONObject volumeObj = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = volumeObj.optString("title");
    String subtitle = volumeObj.optString("subtitle");
    JSONArray authorsArray = volumeObj.getJSONArray("authors");
    String publisher = volumeObj.optString("publisher");
    String publishedDate = volumeObj.optString("publishedDate");
    String description = volumeObj.optString("description");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done this before but still got very strange outputs. I figured out that the JSON data I get from the API was broken. I'll have to figure out another way.